# How can I associate objects as models using ng-options in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Assume I have two objects: color and shirt.

Each shirt can have multiple properties as well as multiple colors which is basically an array of color objects.

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
        {
            label:"Red",
            value:"r-e-d",
            available:true
        },
        {
            label:"Blue",
            value:"b-l-u-e",
            available:false
        }   
    ];

    $scope.shirts=[{
        size:"M",
        cost:100,
        colors:[ ]
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I use `ng-options` to append/remove `color` objects to/from `shirts.color`?

I want to associate `scope.color` objects to `scope.shirts.color` objects so that if I change something like name of the color or code of the color, then the corresponding items in the associated `color` objects in `shirts.colors` should also get updated automatically.

From what I know about `ng-options` and `ng-model`, I will have to create new objects for colors and set its values based on what is selected in the select box, but those objects will be independent of the color objects and changing the color objects will not update the corresponding objects in shirts.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ng-options` for that directly:

```
Color: <select multiple ng:model="shirt.colors" ng:options="c.value as c.label for c in colors"></select>
```

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQQxrSE89iY1BnfumK0A?p=preview

*update*

And about editing of source `colors`: if in shirt's color you store just value, it would be extremely hard to detect what was item was changed and re-select it in options (changed selected item unselects because AngularJS don't know reason of change).

As workaround you can select objects, not values. I've updated plunker.

Comment: I have a followup question i.e. how can I use checkboxes instead of select multiple to manage that array of objects.
I have asked that question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785273/use-checkboxes-in-angularjs-to-manage-array-of-objects