# Use checkboxes in angularjs to manage array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I had asked a question about 
[How to associate objects as models using ng-options in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751674/how-can-i-associate-objects-as-models-using-ng-options-in-angularjs/14753629).

And I got an awesome answer very fast. My followup questions is that the response uses `<select mutiple>` to handle the child object array.

You can see a working example of what I want, working with `<select>` at http://plnkr.co/edit/FQQxrSE89iY1BnfumK0A?p=preview

How can I use `<input type='checkbox'>` (instead of `<select>`) to handle that object array i.e. `ng:model="shirt.colors"` while repeating the items from `colors` object array.

The reason, this appears so complicated to me is that I have to manage an array of objects instead of array of values... for example, if you look in the fiddle, there are `color` objects and `shirt` object that has multiple colors.

If the `color` object changes, it should change the corresponding `color` objects in `shirt` objects.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need some intermediate value in your scope, and bind checkboxes to it. In your controller - watch for it changes, and manually reconstruct shirt.colors, according to it value.

```
<div ng-repeat='shirt in shirts'>
  <h3>Shirt.</h3>
  <label>Size: <input ng-model='shirt.size'></label><br/>
  <label>Colors:</label>
  <label ng-repeat="color in colors">
    {{color.label}} <input ng-model="selection[$parent.$index][$index]" type="checkbox"/>
  </label>

    </label>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selection = [[],[]];
$scope.$watch('selection', function () {
  console.log('change', $scope.selection);
  angular.forEach($scope.selection, function (shirtSelection, index) {
    $scope.shirts[index].colors = [];
    angular.forEach(shirtSelection, function (value, index2) {
      if (value) $scope.shirts[index].colors.push($scope.colors[index2]);
    });
  });
}, true);
```

You can test it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lh9hTa9wM5fkh3nT09RJ?p=preview

Comment: Awesome - Great idea!  In addition to using Pythonic's concept, I used this 3rd party directive which helped simplify dealing with Angular's approach to checkboxes.  http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Comment: we need to handle if user uncheks chekbox by checking vaule is false.